# Write a grayscale image to file in VTK

Tags: c++, image, vtk, grayscale

I have a **grayscale** image with decimal pixel intencities `from 0.0 to 1.0`, which is stored in `std::vector< std::vector<double> >`.
I want to write this image as 1-channel grayscale image (1-byte per pixel) using VTK.
I need to store pixels without any compression or deformation.
What I have so far:

```
        typedef std::vector< std::vector<double> > a2DImage;
        a2DImage img = getImageSomehow(...);

        vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageCanvasSource2D> imageCanvas = 
            vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageCanvasSource2D>::New();

        imageCanvas->SetExtent(0, img.size() - 1, 0, img[0].size() - 1, 0, 0);

        for (size_t i = 0; i < img.size(); i++) {
            for (size_t j = 0; j < img[i].size(); j++) {
                unsigned char color = 
                                (static_cast<unsigned char>(img[i][j] * 255));
                imageCanvas->SetScalarTypeToUnsignedChar();
                imageCanvas->SetDrawColor(color);
                imageCanvas->DrawPoint(i, j); 
            }
        }

        imageCanvas->Update();
        //vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageData> imageData = imageCanvas->GetOutput();

        vtkSmartPointer<vtkBMPWriter> writer = 
                                         vtkSmartPointer<vtkBMPWriter>::New();
        writer->SetFileName((filenameBMP).c_str());
        writer->SetInputConnection(imageCanvas->GetOutputPort());
        writer->Write();
```

But `vtkBMPWriter` saves image to disk as RGB and I don't see any methods to set into grayscale.

Comment: If you only write 1 bit per pixel, you will lose all tonal gradation beteen 0 and 1.0...

Comment: sorry, 1 byte per pixel :)

Comment: `Monochrome` is not supported by `vtkBMPWriter`, will always write `RGB`. Use `vtkImageWriter` to write 1 byte per pixel.